# Visual Studio blocks the UI for minutes at a time for C++/XAML file

Tags: c++, xaml, visual-studio-2012, directx-11

Every time I view my XAML file, Visual Studio hangs for several minutes (the UI is blocked completely).  I'm working with a DirectX/C++ project with a XAML wrapper (using SwapChainBackgroundPanel).

What I've tried:

- Using the `Windows::ApplicationModel::DesignMode::DesignModeEnabled` condition in the code behind
- Using XAML mode only (not split view or design mode)
- Lighting myself on fire

The hanging persists.  I'm so desperate that I've resorted to using Notepad++ to edit this one file, but then I don't have Visual Studio to catch my dumb typos.

Is there any imaginable way around this?

Comment: Is it just a monster size xaml file? Options would be Expression Blend, or kxaml.

Comment: @ChrisW it's not that big, 400 lines.  There's a lot in the code-behind, though.  Thanks for the kxaml tip, I didn't know about that.

Comment: It shouldn't choke like you describe on just 400 lines of xaml :/ will be curious to see if anyone puts their finger on the issue too.

Answer (score 2):

first of all try [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1858820.aspx/1).
Also I recommend to disable design view default for XAML files in options:
`Tools -> Options... -> Text Editor -> XAML -> Misc -> Always open documents in full XAML view`.

FYI: [this](http://lennybacon.com/post/2010/10/18/ultimateguidetospeedupvisualstudio) recommendations made my VS2012 faster.

Comment: The "always open in full XAML" option seems to have solved my problem - thanks a million!  Thanks also for the general VS tips link.

Comment: Argh ... I spoke too soon.  The hanging seemed to be gone at first, but now it is back with a vengeance.  I'm going to unaccept -- nothing personal, just want to leave the question open in case someone has any more insight.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what was causing this, but subsequent experiences with VS2012 have taught me a likely culprit.  (And Michael alluded to this in his answer.)  The XAML designer spawns multiple processes, each of which are unfathomable memory hogs.  I have taken to offing these so-called "XDesProc.exe" via the Task Manager, with extreme prejudice.